# Запрет загрузки приложений на iphone 4s

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Возможно ли отказаться от загрузок приложения на iphone 4s при добавлении приложения в App Store, либо при разработке программы в xcode? Не получается подогнать дизайн под 4s, начиная с 5 и до 6s plus все получается отлично, а вот 4s хромает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению нет.

Можно выбрать платформу iPhone/iPad/Universal, чтобы избавиться от всех устройств какого то типа.

Можно выбрать минимальную совместимую верcию iOS, чтобы не поддерживать старые устройства. Поскольку iPhone 4s поддерживает все версии включая iOS9, этот подход не сработает.

На всякий случай добавлю: Аппстор выдаст ошибку при загрузке новой версии, если она поддерживает меньше устройств, чем предыдущая ([информация тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html)). Если найдете способ отказаться от поддержки 4s, скорее всего придется убирать приложение из стора и загружать снова с другим bundle_id.